# How can I import sources generated by the Protocol Buffers compiler?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am using the Protocol Buffers compiler to generate Python source code.

The directory structure it generates looks like

```
namespace/
|-- package1/
|   \-- messages_pb2.py
|-- package2/
    \-- messages_pb2.py
```

It does not include `__init__.py` files. Given that the compiler wipes the whole directory structure on each compilation, adding the `__init__.py` files is not an option, and suggests that the built sources are intended to be imported some other ways.

I have tried adding the path to `namespace` to `sys.path` but for some reason the import still fails:

```
>>> from sys import path
>>> path.append(... absolute path to `namespace` ...)
>>> import package1.messages_pb2
... ImportError ...
```

How are the Protocol Buffers generated sources intended to be used?

So notes:

- I am using Python 2.7
- Some of the `messages_pb2` modules reference the other packages. So `package2.messages_pb2` might have `from namespace.package1 import messages_pb2`

I use Python very infrequently and am not coming up with a solution.

Comment: My solution for now is to switch to Python3. For some reason imports work differently, though I'm not sure why